# How to I scan using find for all files that do have execute bit set?

Tags: find

I want to write a permission fix script that uses find to fix permissions on files.

Mainly what I need is a find command that is able to list all files with execute bit set, regardless of the other permissions on the file (that's the trick).

Comment: What have you already tried? What research have you done? As written right now, you're just asking us to do your work for you, and you haven't shown any effort whatsoever in solving this yourself.

Comment: Also, I'd highly recommend reading up on what types of questions are appropriate here before posting any more questions. You have quite a string of closed and down voted questions, and if not careful, you will likely run afoul of the automatic question ban.

Comment: @EEAA: Sadly, I doubt that's anywhere near close to happening. If you have any rep at all it's really hard to get q-banned.

Comment: @Iain - fair enough. Hopefully he'll still heed the advice, though.

Comment: @EEAA: I hope so too but people who can't be bothered to read manuals generally don't heed advice - they just find it easier to whinge about our attitude `...` iyswim ;)

Answer (score 36):

On GNU's find:

```
find /dir -type f -executable
```

On other versions, see the man page around `-perm`.

Answer (score 17):

Believe it or not this is extensively documented in the [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) man page. On the CentOS and Ubuntu systems I have to hand there are even examples of this.

> -perm /mode
>
> Any  of  the  permission  bits  mode are set for the file.  Symbolic modes are accepted in this form.  You must
>                 specify `u',`g' or `o' if you use a symbolic mode.  See the EXAMPLES section for some  illustrative  examples.
>                 If  no  permission bits in mode are set, this test matches any file (the idea here is to be consistent with the
>                 behaviour of -perm -000).

So

```
find  . -perm /u+x
```

will find files where execute permission is set for the owner

```
find . -perm /u+x,o+x
```

will find files where execute permission is set for the owner and other and so on.

Answer (score -1):

Without using the find command, on zsh we can do something like this using [`Glob Qualifiers`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
ls /path/to/some/parent/folder/**/*(*)
```

The above `ls` command will return all files in all subfolders of `/path/to/some/parent/folder`, which are executable.